# MySQL nested query: returning single row and multiple row queries from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, nested

I have two tables: invoice and charges, with a one-to-many relationship. (simplified) invoice has: id, description, date as fields and charges has: id, id_invoice, price, qty, date as fields

For invoice generation I need the info from the invoice table where e.g. id=1 and also all the info from the charges table where id_invoice=1 (so one row from invoice and multiple rows from charges)

At the moment I've got two separate queries but I was wondering if it was possible to do this in a single query?

Thanks

Comment: Could we see those queries please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do a simple `JOIN` between the two tables joining on `invoice.id=charges.id_invoice`

The invoice fields would be returned identically for every charge on the same invoice but it'd allow you to fetch the data in a single query.

The query would look something like:

```
SELECT * FROM invoice i, charges c WHERE i.id=c.id_invoice ORDER BY i.id;
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Would this be more efficient from a DB load perspective than two separate queries?

Comment: It's hard to say. There'll be less work for the client (there's only one query instead of two) but there's more overall data which could create more network traffic. I suspect there's very little in it.

Answer (score 0):

For your needs, a LEFT JOIN seems better. Ex:

```
SELECT * FROM invoice i LEFT JOIN charges c ON i.id=c.id_invoice ORDER BY i.id;
```

A nice illustration of SQL joins can be found [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)